# Django ajax error

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-templates

I am getting an error while using AJAX to populate a table inside my django template. I am not sure what the error is, please help me in resolving this issue. I have shared all the important files, if I remove ajax and redirect the url to the destination URL then the code works fine, but somehow the ajax implementation is throwing an error.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64879)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\Users\mayayadav\djcode\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serv
ers\basehttp.py", line 150, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in yo
ur host machine
```

Views.py

```
def SearchTrips(request):
    city=request.POST['city'].replace(" ","%20")
    location=request.POST['location'].replace(" ","%20")
    duration=request.POST['duration']
    print city
    print location
    url="http://blankket-mk8te7kbzv.elasticbeanstalk.com/getroutes?city="+city+"&location="+location+"&duration="+duration
    print url
    x=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    datas=json.load(x)          
    return render(request,'searchtrips.html',{'datas':datas})
```

Ajax.js

```
$(function(){

        $("#routes").submit(function() {

             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/searchtrips/',
                    data: {
                    'city' : $('#city').val(),
                    'location' : $('#location').val(),
                    'duration' : $('#duration').val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
                    },                    
                success:searchSuccess,
                datatype: 'html'
                });
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#routeTable').html(data);
};
```

searchtrips.html

```
                    {% for data in datas %}
            <tr>
                            <td>{{ data.score}}</td>
                            {%for element in data.place.elements%}
                            <td>{{element.placeName}} </td>
                            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

htmlfile

```
    <form class="form-search"  action ="" id="routes" method="post" name="routes" align="center">
........................

{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" class=""> <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i> Search </button>

</form>

<table class="table table-hover" id="routeTable" style="display:none">
    <thead>
        <tr>
```

Score Cost
    Itinerary

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in return function. When you use an ajax you must not return it in render.

```
if request.is_ajax():
    return HttpResponse(datas, mimetype="application/javascript")
else:
    return render(request,'searchtrips.html',{'datas':datas})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your view is hanged or throwing exception.

First in you ajax, you should prevent it submit several times:

```
$("#routes").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/searchtrips/',
        datatype: 'html',
        data: {
            'city' : $('#city').val(),
            'location' : $('#location').val(),
            'duration' : $('#duration').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },                    
        success: function (resp) {
            console.log('Success');
            $('#routeTable').html(resp);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Next in your view, you might want to catch exception if there is any:

```
def SearchTrips(request):
    city = request.POST['city'].replace(" ","%20")
    location = request.POST['location'].replace(" ","%20")
    duration = request.POST['duration']
    url = "http://blankket-mk8te7kbzv.elasticbeanstalk.com/getroutes?city=%s&location=%s&duration=%s" % (city, location, duration)

    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except:
        resp = None

    if resp:
        datas = json.load(resp)
    else:
        datas = None

    return render(request, 'searchtrips.html', {'datas': datas})
```

Also make sure that you read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) since your code styling and naming convention is quite bad.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am new to python/coding and this really helps, I would definitely read PEP 8. However I tried with your recommendations and now the ajax function is getting called. Can you please tell me if I am missing anything on the HTML side as well. Thanks!

Comment: Ajax success is getting called is a good sign, right? what's the problem?

Comment: I am sorry I meant Ajax function is "not" getting called

Comment: Please check my edited answer. Try again and check console for debug message / error. Console is your friend. I'm sure you can debug yourself then

Comment: Thanks! there was some issue with my ajax, I debugged and solved it.

Comment: what was the problem exactly? Since your final code doesn't look so different to the first one

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new ajax.js code(just to close this thread and for anyones future reference)

```
$(function(){

    $('#searchtest').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/searchtrips/",
            data: {
                'city' : $('#city').val(),
                'location' : $('#location').val(),
                'duration' : $('#duration').val(),
                'search_text' : $('#searchtest').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```