# Connection errors due to webpage navigation

Tags: python, ajax, django, connection

I am having some trouble with connection errors in my Django app when a user navigates to a different page before AJAX call is finished.
So, when the client-side sends several AJAX calls for save/load/retrieve data etc., and when a user navigates to a different page - say when an AJAX call was just made from the client side to save the content, the content is saved and the functionally everything is fine, but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50646)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\socket.py", line 594, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\socketserver.py", line 625, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "D:\Applications\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 36, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

For example, an AJAX call for the URL `/xyz/save/` is sent, and before its callback is executed on the client side, the user navigates to a URL `/xyz/abc`, I get the above error. I understand that the connection for `/xyz/save/` is interrupted, how do I avoid this?

Comment: if the ajax is for saving the data, I guess you can use atomic requests,[database transaction docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/) may be this will sort it

Comment: You are using Django's built-in development server?

Comment: @ChintanJoshi My app uses AJAX requests for other purposes such as retrieving content (ex: from S3) also. Could that also be solved using atomic requests?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes. I am still testing it locally on my desktop. I have not yet setup uWSGI or Mod_WSGI. Could this problem be because of that?

Comment: The development server has several limitations. You shouldn't start worrying before this happens in a production setup.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040898/django-ajax-error) can help, I have never tried to retrieve content with atomic requests so cant say about that.

Comment: @ChintanJoshi I already saw that. I am not returning render for AJAX, only a HttpResponse object.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the suggestion! I will try emulating this in a production environment!